# Entity Framework - Query to obtain last 2 unique entries of a column and then their relevant data

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new to entity framework and I am having difficulty coming up with a query. For the following situation.Say I have the following model

```
class Student
{
 [Key]
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string name{get;set;}
 public string guid{get;set;}
}
```

and my table looks like this

```
   id|   name | guid
       --------------
   1  Andrew | C
   2  John   | D
   3  Adam   | B
   4  Charles| A
   5  Jacob  | A
```

Now I would like to get the last two unique GUIDs which will be `A` and `B`.
and then I would like to get all row in which these GUIS appeared in the table. so I would like Jacob,Charles and Adam returned. Any suggestions on how I can get started with this ? I know Ill have to sortby then select unique. But I am not sure how Ill do it in Entity.

Comment: One more thing to point out is that I would use System.Guid in stead of a string in the student class given my database uses the Data Type uniqueidentifier.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could do something like this:

```
var result = dbcontext.Students.OrderByDescending(s => s.Id)
                      .GroupBy(s => s.Guid)
                      .Take(2)
                      .SelectMany(s => s.Take(1));
```

1- Order by Id descending to get to the last Id's first.

2- Then group by the Guid and take the first 2 groups.

3- Select the top 1 for each group.

Comment: As OP Expected output is Jacob,Charles and Adam you need to take all instead of `Take(2).SelectMany(s => s.ToList(1));`

Answer (score 2):

> You need to only use this if you want output as `Jacob,Charles and Adam`

Original Credits **@Stackberg** use suggested query like without `Take` if the indented result.

```
//This work against in memory list (TESTED)
var result = dbcontext.Students.OrderByDescending(s => s.Id)
                      .GroupBy(s => s.Guid)
                      .Take(2)
                      .SelectMany(s=>s.ToList());

//IF EF doesn't able to convert the query you can try this.

var inMemoryGrouped = dbcontext.Students.OrderByDescending(s => s.Id)
                      .GroupBy(s => s.Guid)
                      .Take(2)
                      .ToList();

//Flatten the items using select many 
var final = inMemoryGrouped.SelectMany(y=>y.ToList());
```

Only thing it differ from @Stackberg answer is omitted the `Take` after grouping.